# Running programm wont adapt to changes

Tags: java, eclipse

i encountered a weird problem thats totally new to me.
My java programm (using Eclipse) works just fine but since a few moments, whenever i change something and run the main method, it runs the program as if nothing has changed. 
For example changing Text or removing/adding textfields to the GUI does not have any effect.
Refreshed the Project already....

Anybody knows to help?

Comment: Try restarting eclipse? Also make sure Project > Build Automatically is enabled.

Comment: Its enabled, restarting Eclipse, rebooting laptop, removing the Project and adding it again.... none worked.

Comment: what type of project?

Comment: Its an JavaFX Project